# Using c# is it possible to detect when the taskbar changes state?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to keep the taskbar hidden as I want users to only use Windows 10 tablets running Windows Home to perform specific functions, my app will hide the taskbar.

However over time when the app is not being used, but running in the background, the taskbar will show up as minimized. Is there a way to detect when this happens and re-hide it?

(Budget constraints prevent the use of Windows Professional which has Kiosk Mode)

Comment: Have you tried setting your application as the shell? You don't really need kiosk mode.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: I have tried that with an electron app, worked fine for my needs. Definitely give it a shot. I don't remember the key where you set that, but I expect you to be enterprising enough to find out on your own. :P

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the subject which tell you how to set up the keys.

Comment: However I would still be interested in an answer to the question if one exists